# How to read a number with leading 0's as one int using scanf in C?

Tags: c

I am using C to read integer data using `scanf("%i", &myInt)`. I know for this particular input the data will ALWAYS be three digits. However, sometimes I need to read a number with leading 0's like 001 or 078. When `scanf()` reads a number with a leading zero it will not pick up the subsequent digits. For example, when I read 078 `scanf` reads 7 then the next `scanf` will read the 8. I would like `scanf` to read 78. Can someone tell me how to do this properly? Here is a code example:

```
int x;

while (scanf("%i", &x) != EOF) {

   //do operations on each of the digits

}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "of course"?  Nothing's that obvious without a code sample.

Comment: read the input as string(`%s`) and convert it to int when you needed by using (`atoi()`)

Comment: What do you mean, it only reads one digit? Are you using `%c` or something? `%d` is the "read an integer" format specifier. See a demo: http://ideone.com/ttYqof

Comment: Can you show us example code that demonstrates the problem? It's not at all clear how you're reading the input.

Comment: `scanf("%d"` will actually read `78` out of `078` etc. If your program does not appear to then please post your code (preferably a complete program along with the input you are providing)

Comment: Use `"%3d"` as the format specifier and it should read exactly three digits

Comment: @Floris No `%3d` does not read exactly three digits. 3 is the maximum field width. The conversion could fail entirely, or it could scan a number with fewer than three digits.  A leading plus or minus sign counts as part of the field width.

Comment: @Kaz you are right. I was too quick (darn iPhone) and had not considered the possibility of a sign in front of the number. You probably want to include that comment under the accepted answer... Incidentally I thought your answer was very good and upvoted as such.

Comment: @cHao I think you took what I meant out of context. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a width delimiter with scanf, even on integer types :

```
int i;
scanf ("%3d",&i); // Will read 3 characters and interpret them as an integer
```

Answer (score 17):

I suspect you may be using the `%i` conversion specifier which honors C conventions like `0x` denoting hex, and leading zeros denoting octal.  If the input is `078` and `%i` is used, then only `07` matches because `8` is not an octal digit. Use `%d` to scan decimal integers.

The `i` in `%i` does not mean "reach for me whenever you need to convert an i)nteger to type i)nt".

The width is only necessary if the three digit number is followed by more digits which we need to exclude from the scan. For instance, we can convert a date given as `"20140417"` into three integers using the format string `"%4d%2d%d"`.  The last `%d` could be `%2d` but doesn't have to be.   These values do not specify how many digits to extract, but rather they specify a *maximum field width*: the conversion takes up to that many characters (including a possible plus or minus sign). For the input `-1234`, the `%3d` conversion will take `-12`, and leave the `34`. For the input `1$`, `%3d` will just take the `1` and leave the `$`, because it isn't a decimal digit.